# ReWrite Rule in IIS using RegEx

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

For the last couple hours I tried to create a ReWrite Rule in IIS which does meet my requirements, but I just don't get it. So maybe someone can help me out :-)

What I have till now is the following:

**Rewrite URL**

```
index.php?page={R:1}&param={R:2}
```

**RegEx Pattern**

```
^(.*)/([0-9]+)
```

This is how I'd like to write my URLs at the end:

- http://url.com/path1/path2/path3/param/ for example http://url.com/news/detail/1/

In this example I should have "news/detail" in "?page" and "1" in "?param".

With the rule I created so far that seems to work quite good, as long as I have a number at the end (param).

My only problem is that I want to make the number (param) optional.

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: What is the definitive rule? How many paths and/or parameters can be specified in the rule?

Comment: @cheesemacfly The definitive rule should be, that there should not be any limit in paths but its enough if one paramter can be set. Paths never have a number in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't come up with something more permissive than this:

```
^([a-z-/]+)([0-9])?
```

Base on your comment `Paths never have a number in it`, I went a bit further and allowed only characters from `a` to `z` (use the ignore case option if needed).
This rule will match any of the following url:

- `news/detail/1/` => `{R:1}` = `news/detail/` and `{R:2}` = `1`
- `news/detail/1` => `{R:1}` = `news/detail/` and `{R:2}` = `1`
- `news/detail/` => `{R:1}` = `news/detail/` and `{R:2}` is empty
- `news/detail` => `{R:1}` = `news/detail` and `{R:2}` is empty

You probably will have to deal with the trailing `/` in your code.

*The limitation comes from the fact that as far as I know, the regex in the rewrite rule doesn't support negative lookahead/lookbehind pattern.*

Answer (score 0):

To allow for the final match capture to be optional put a ? by it. Also specify that it will be at the by anchoring it with the end character $.

```
^(.*)/?(\d+)?$
```

I have also made the final / optional since if there is no digit you don't want match to fail if it does not have a / at the end (which should be optional).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the result is that everything is in {R:1} (?page) - any idea why?

Comment: @Crasher .* is greedy (in regex parlance) says give me *everything*. .*? says give me most, but stop at first hint of change. Regardless you don't have anything that would stop .* getting everything.